# npm install changes resolved from a URL to false

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

## The Problem

When I pull my team's code and run `npm install` a number of items in `package-lock.json` have their `resolved` property change from a URL to `false`. E.g.

```
"debug": {
  "version": "3.2.6",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-3.2.6.tgz",
  …
},

// changes to 

"debug": {
  "version": "3.2.6",
  "resolved": false,
  …
},
```

## The Ask

I would like this *not* to happen. I don't understand why it is happening or what could be causing it. It seems like a pretty odd and serious bug. What would happen if I checked this in and deployed? ‍♂️

## The Details

`npm -v #=> 6.14.5`

`node -v #=> v12.13.0`

Comment: This is a bug and seems to have to do with using npm link. But it’s also mostly inconsequential as since npm 5, the resolved field is basically ignored. Just messes with your commit history a little.

Comment: Thanks @bryan60. I'm not aware of us using `npm link` anywhere. Is this something that is done automatically or by the packages I'm installing?

Comment: it's an issue with npm itself, slated to be resolved in 7. but for the time being, it's just annoying more than it is harmful. People have said you can fix it by deleting your node modules and doing a fresh install

Comment: Interesting! I've confirmed that `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` does not reproduce the error. Is this happening for _everyone_ using npm because I haven't heard much about it at work (maybe people are used to ignoring it) and didn't find much in my search before posting this question.

Comment: well, it's mostly associated with using npm link, which is newer and less commonly used, though apparently not in all cases. It's possible most people affected don't even notice it. I mostly just accept any package lock changes without reviewing them so long as the package.json itself is correct since it's a generated file and all. idc what npm is doing under the hood so long as it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

As @bryan60 has pointed out this is a bug in NPM, specifically with `npm link`. There's nothing we can do at this point except wait for the update.

## Work Around

If you are having problem and have a few minutes `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install` will reinstall all of your node modules and you won't have the `package-lock.json` problem.